# Is there a way to make API calls from a Postgres Database?

Tags: postgresql, rest, facebook-graph-api, google-api, amazon-rds

My Postgres Database is on Amazon RDS.
Is it possible to make API calls (HTTPS) directly from there?

Comment: Unlikely. You would need an untrusted procedural language, and that would require a superuser.

Comment: i.e. not possible on RDS?

Comment: I would be surprised if they allowed that on a hosted database.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I found this in RDS's documentation
"Extension plv8 update – plv8 is a procedural language that you can use to write functions in JavaScript that you can then call from SQL. This release of PostgreSQL supports version 2.1.0 of plv8."
 
source
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html

Comment: Give it a try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @LaurenzAlbe
"Unlikely. You would need an untrusted procedural language, and that would require a superuser. and that is probably not allowed on a hosted database like Amazon RDS"

I also looked up some [extensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Extensions) that Amazon RDS allows but I could not find any that allowed API calls. So, for now, it seems that there's no way to do HTTPS requests from PostgreSQL on RDS.